# How to use numpy.eye function with custom diagonal values?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use a single line of code to make a matrix with zeros except a custom value for the diagonals. I am able to do it like the code I put below, but am wondering if I can do it by only using np.eye?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.eye(4,4 k=0)  
np.fill_diagonal (a,4)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

try the `identity` matrix in numpy module:

```
a=np.identity(10)*4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `np.eye()` altogether and just use `np.fill_diagonal()` on a zeroed matrix, if you are not using any of its features:

```
import numpy as np


def value_eye_fill(value, n):
    result = np.zeros((n, n))
    np.fill_diagonal(result, value)
    return result
```

That should be the fastest approach for larger inputs, within NumPy.

---

Of course you can also use `np.eye()` and avoid `np.fill_diagonal()` by just multiplying the value by the result of `np.eye()`:

```py
import numpy as np


def value_eye_fill(value, n):
    return value * np.eye(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.eye(4)*4
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np


custom_diagonal_values = [ ]

matrix_size = len(custom_diagonal_values)
custom_matrix = np.zeroes(matrix_size, matrix_size)

np.fill_diagonal(custom_matrix, custom_diagonal_values)

print(custom_matrix)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.